# Why Intellij project classpath broken?

Tags: java

My java project can not read application.properties file config,the ConfigurationProperties get null property.When I print the class path using code:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableCaching
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader) classLoader).getURLs();
        for (URL url : urls) {
            System.out.println("classpath:" + url.getFile());
        }

        //SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        //app.addListeners(new ApplicationPidFileWriter("app.pid"));
        //app.run(args);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin\java.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:28450,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:C:\Users\hlpc\.IdeaIC2018.2\system\groovyHotSwap\gragent.jar -javaagent:C:\Users\hlpc\.IdeaIC2018.2\system\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar=file:/C:/Users/hlpc/AppData/Local/Temp/capture1.props -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.5\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper C:\Users\hlpc\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_classpath374768014 creditsystem.Application
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:28450', transport: 'socket'
classpath:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20Community%20Edition%202018.2.5/lib/idea_rt.jar
classpath:/C:/Users/hlpc/.IdeaIC2018.2/system/groovyHotSwap/gragent.jar
classpath:/C:/Users/hlpc/.IdeaIC2018.2/system/captureAgent/debugger-agent.jar
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:28450', transport: 'socket'
```

Q1：Why the project class path only have 2 item?

Q2: I marked the src dir to source root,when I refresh gradle,the source root dir turn to gray(not source root)!!Why?Where is my project problem. I am using Windows 10 + Intellij Idea 2018 + Gradle 3.2.1。This is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.6.RELEASE'
        jacksonVersion = '2.8.7'
        springfoxVersion = '2.6.1'
        poiVersion = "3.14"
        aspectjVersion = '1.7.4'
    }
    ext['tomcat.version'] = '8.0.35'
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://repox.gtan.com:8078'
        }
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.springframework.build.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.7")
    }
}

tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}
tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

//编译JAVA文件时采用UTF-8
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

//编译groovy代码时采用 UTF-8
tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
    groovyOptions.encoding = "MacRoman"
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    description = 'Generates gradlew[.bat] scripts'
    gradleVersion = '3.2.1'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

def ccCommonBuildScript = file("$rootDir/gradle/common.gradle")
def ccDataLibs = fileTree(dir: "$rootDir/cc-data/lib", include: '*.jar')
def ccCommonDir = fileTree(dir: "$rootDir/cc-common/lib",include : '*.jar')
project(':cc-common') {
    apply from: ccCommonBuildScript

    description = 'credit-system-common'

    dependencies {
        compile project(':hl-util')
        compile("com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_$scalaLibVersion:2.4.17")
        compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_$scalaLibVersion:$jacksonVersion")
        compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:$jacksonVersion")
        compile('com.google.guava:guava:21.0')
        compile("ma.glasnost.orika:orika-core:1.4.6")
        compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:${springfoxVersion}")
        compile("io.swagger:swagger-scala-module_$scalaLibVersion:1.0.3")
        compile group: 'net.sf.ehcache', name: 'ehcache', version: '2.10.3'
        compile group: 'commons-digester', name: 'commons-digester', version: '2.1'
        compile "commons-discovery:commons-discovery:0.2"
        compile "wsdl4j:wsdl4j:1.6.2"
        compile "org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:3.1.10"
        compile "org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.10"
        compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-bindings-soap', version: '3.1.10'
        compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-ws-addr', version: '3.1.10'
        compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-wsdl', version: '3.1.10'
        compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-ws-policy', version: '3.1.10'
        compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4.7'
        compile "org.apache.neethi:neethi:3.0.2"
        compile "org.apache.cxf:cxf:3.1.10"
        compile group: 'org.codehaus.woodstox', name: 'stax2-api', version: '3.1.4'
        compile group: 'xml-apis', name: 'xml-apis', version: '1.0.b2'
        compile group: 'xml-resolver', name: 'xml-resolver', version: '1.2'
        compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.3'
        compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
        compile("org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.2")
        compile ccCommonDir
        compile("org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.1")
    }
}

project(':cc-data') {
    apply from: ccCommonBuildScript

    description = 'credit-system-data'

    dependencies {
        compile project(':cc-common')
        compile project(':hl-data-mybatis')

        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc') {
            exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat'
        }
        compile group: 'org.mybatis.spring.boot', name: 'mybatis-spring-boot-starter', version: '1.3.0'
        compile('com.zaxxer:HikariCP:2.6.0')
        compile('org.mongodb:bson:3.4.2')
        compile("org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.10")
        compile group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: '2.6'
        compile('org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.10')
        compile ccDataLibs
    }
}

project(':cc-integration') {
    apply from: ccCommonBuildScript

    description = 'credit-system-integration'

    dependencies {
        compile project(':cc-data')

        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    }
}

project(':cc-web-webservice') {
    apply from: ccCommonBuildScript

    description = 'credit-system-webservice'
    dependencies {
        compile project(':cc-business')
        compile project(':cc-data')
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')
    }
}
project(':cc-business') {
    apply from: ccCommonBuildScript

    description = 'credit-system-business'

    configurations {
        ajc
        aspects
    }

    dependencies {
        compile project(':cc-data')
        compile project(':cc-integration')
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')
        compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat', name: 'tomcat-juli', version: property('tomcat.version')
        compile("org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.6.10")
        ajc "org.aspectj:aspectjtools:1.6"
        compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: '1.6.12'
        aspects "org.springframework:spring-aspects:3.2.2.RELEASE"
        compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws', version: '3.1.6'
        compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty', version: '3.1.6'
        compile group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.10.2'
        compile('com.alibaba:fastjson:1.2.35')
        compile group: 'commons-beanutils', name: 'commons-beanutils', version: '1.9.3'

        compile group: 'javax.transaction', name: 'jta', version: '1.1'
        compile group: 'ma.glasnost.orika', name: 'orika-core', version: '1.5.1'
        compile group: 'com.mashape.unirest', name: 'unirest-java', version: '1.3.0'
        compile group: 'org.apache.axis2', name: 'axis2-kernel', version: '1.7.6'
        compile group: 'org.apache.axis2', name: 'axis2-adb', version: '1.7.6'
        compile group: 'org.apache.axis2', name: 'axis2-transport-local', version: '1.7.6'
        compile group: 'org.apache.axis2', name: 'axis2-transport-http', version: '1.7.6'
        compile group: 'org.apache.axis2', name: 'axis2', version: '1.7.6', ext: 'pom'
    }
}

/*compileJava{
    options.encoding="UTF-8"
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation" << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:-options" << "-Xlint:unchecked"
}*/

project(':cc-api') {
    apply from: ccCommonBuildScript
    description = 'credit-system-api'

    dependencies {
        compile project(':cc-business')
        compile 'io.rest-assured:json-path:3.0.1'
        compile 'org.testng:testng:6.8.17'
        compile('com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured:2.3.1')
        testCompile 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured:3.0.1'
    }
}

project(':cc-web') {
    apply from: ccCommonBuildScript

    description = 'credit-system-web'

    dependencies {
        compile project(':cc-business')
        compile project(':cc-api')
        compile project(':cc-common')
        compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:${springfoxVersion}")
        compile 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'
        compile group: 'org.java-websocket', name: 'Java-WebSocket', version: '1.3.0'
        compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-websocket', version: '5.0.0.RELEASE'
        compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-messaging', version: '4.3.14.RELEASE'
    }
}
project(':cc-web-websocket') {
    apply from: ccCommonBuildScript

    description = 'credit-system-websocket'

    dependencies {
        compile project(':cc-business')
        compile project(':cc-common')
        compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-websocket', version: '1.5.9.RELEASE'
        compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '4.3.10.RELEASE'
        compile group: 'com.alibaba', name: 'druid', version: '1.1.5'
    }
}

project(':cc-web-boot') {
    apply from: ccCommonBuildScript

    description = 'credit-system-web-boot'

    jar {
        baseName = "credit-system-web-boot"
    }

    task copyTask(type: Copy) {
        from "$projectDir/build/libs/credit-system-web-boot-${version}.jar"
        into "$projectDir/build/libs/api"
        rename "credit-system-web-boot-${version}.jar", "credit-system-web-api-${version}.jar"
    }

    dependencies {
        compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools"
        compile project(':cc-web')
        compile project(':cc-web-webservice')
        compile project(':cc-web-websocket')
    }
}

project(':cc-web-war') {
    apply from: ccCommonBuildScript

    apply plugin: 'war'

    description = 'credit-system-web-war'

    war {
        baseName = "credit-system-web-war"
    }

    configurations {
        providedRuntime
    }

    dependencies {
        compile project(':cc-web')
        compile project(':cc-web-webservice')
        providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    }
}

project(':cc-etl-sechedule') {
    apply from: ccCommonBuildScript

    description = 'credit-etl-sechedule'

    jar {
        baseName = "credit-etl-sechedule-boot"
    }

    dependencies {
        compile project(':cc-data')
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
        compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')
        compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat") {
            exclude(group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed')
        }
        compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat', name: 'tomcat-juli', version: property('tomcat.version')
        compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:${springfoxVersion}")
    }
}
```

Comment: IntelliJ uses a class path file with the real class path. Why are using such an antique version of Gradle? Post your build.gradle

Comment: The build.gradle is pasted.@Strelok

Comment: Is the file layout standard? As in src/main/java and src/main/resources?

Comment: This file build.gradle is in root of project dir.@Strelok

Answer (score 0):

Specify the absolute path of config file like this:

```
 @PropertySource(value = { "file:c:/application.properties" })
```